# How to make slideshow of images that layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm looking to make a slideshow of images that stack on top of each other as you click, and then older images disappear as you continue (like [here](https://fabric.format.com/))

This is what I have so far, but I'm not very familiar with javascript so am not sure where I'm going wrong or how to add even more images that would continue to work and then disappear.

(I've found lots of answers to similar questions but no other solutions have worked so far!)

```js
var timesClicked = 0;

$("#menu_button").click(function() {
    timesClicked++;

    if (timesClicked=2) {
        function showStuff(id) {
            document.getElementById(img-3).style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    else {
        function showStuff(id) {
            document.getElementById(img-3).style.display = "block";
        }
    }

})
```

```html
<img src="https://i0.wp.com/wattlecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/01_PES-1.jpg?zoom=1.5&w=1200" style="height: 60vw;" />        
<div id="a_x200" style="display:none;"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487631807774-f9faa5694358?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1900&q=80" style="width: 40vw;" /></div>

<img id="img-3" src="https://c.stocksy.com/a/vpD800/z9/1959815.jpg?1551161499" style="width: 20vw; display: none;" />

        <input type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff('a_x200');"></input>
```

Comment: Did you add reference of jquery.js file in your page?

Comment: @Yogesh   The only code on that whole page is above, so if the necessary reference is not there then no I don't think so? What would that entail? Thanks so much!

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Add above line in your html page. It will add reference of jquery.js by CDN.

Comment: note that `$("#menu_button").click(function()` was a jQuery so you need to add reference of jQuery or remove them and use plain vanilla javascript.

Comment: There can be lot of different ways to implement this.
And that website on the link seems to show current and the last image on stack. Which simplifies your problem if it's the same. And the implementation detail would be quite a long answer. So, if you don't get answers in few hours, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: do you know CSS? ... have you ever heard of z-index?

Comment: she don't know anything about jQuery and she wants to make whole slideshow or maybe she is asking us to make whole slideshow therefore the question is off Topic

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I do know CSS and I do know what z-index is, my issue isn't with layering the images on top of one another, I can do that easily, I just can't get them to appear and disappear with subsequent clicks of a button

Comment: Why do you define the two functions as exactly the same, but conditionally?

Comment: @ina please learn basic of JQuery https://www.w3schools.com/ , how to call function and all that stuff then ask question when you stuck...

Comment: @Qirel What should I be doing instead?  This code was working to change background colours but I'm not sure what I've done wrong so it doesn't work with images now. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, it's redundant to define two equal functions in a condition like that - `showStuff()` ends up being defined the exact same way every time.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Thanks so much for your help! I actually have learnt the basics of JQuery, thanks for the suggestion though! But as this is getting more complex (for me) I haven't been able to find any tutorials for how to make this specific scenario work. I've tried it this way because of an answer someone else gave on this site, so I assumed it wouldn't be completely incorrect. Like I said though, I'm not very familiar with this language so it would be great if you would be able to provide any solutions or tell me what I've done wrong (specifically), if you know how. Thanks!

Comment: @Qirel I've changed the name of the second function, is that what you were suggesting? The functions still don't work though, is there another reason? Thanks so much for that tip though I'll keep it in mind in the future, I really appreciate it!

Comment: you may be looking to do something like ```document.getElementById(img-3).style.display = "none";``` in your **else** condition. Also, the **timesClicked** should reset when you hide it. But the code is a bit confusing to guess the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to make a slideshow of images that stack on top of each other as you click, and then older images disappear as you continue (like [here](https://fabric.format.com/))

This is what I have so far, but I'm not very familiar with javascript so am not sure where I'm going wrong or how to add even more images that would continue to work and then disappear.

(I've found lots of answers to similar questions but no other solutions have worked so far!)

```js
var timesClicked = 0;

$("#menu_button").click(function() {
    timesClicked++;

    if (timesClicked=2) {
        function showStuff(id) {
            document.getElementById(img-3).style.display = "block";
        }
    } else {
        function showStuff(id) {
            document.getElementById(img-3).style.display = "block";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i0.wp.com/wattlecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/01_PES-1.jpg?zoom=1.5&w=1200" style="height: 60vw;" />        
<div id="a_x200" style="display:none;"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487631807774-f9faa5694358?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1900&q=80" style="width: 40vw;" /></div>

<img id="img-3" src="https://c.stocksy.com/a/vpD800/z9/1959815.jpg?1551161499" style="width: 20vw; display: none;" />

<input type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff('a_x200');"></input>
```

I have added reference jquery.js by CDN in html file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Run my code snippet, it will load image.

Comment: Thanks so much @YogeshPatel , however when I press the button to load the next image it comes up with the error {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: showStuff is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 80
} and I'm not sure what to change to fix that